# Made an AngularJS CKEditor directive draggable and resizable, but now can't format anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ckeditor

First some code... the HTML:

```
<div draggable resizeable id="module_id" style="left:{{module.x}}px; top:{{module.y}}px; width:{{module.width}}px"> 
    <button class="module_move_handle"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></button>
    <button class="module_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    <div ck-editor contenteditable="true" ng-model="test1234"></div>
</div>
```

And the directive:

```
myApp.directive('ckEditor', function () {
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, element, attr, ngModel, ngModelCtrl) {
            var editor_id = element[0].id;

            element.bind('focus', function () {
                if (CKEDITOR.instances[editor_id] === undefined) {
                    var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(element[0], {
                        toolbar: [
                            ['Source'],
                            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
                            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript',
                                'Outdent', 'Indent', 'RemoveFormat'],
                            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
                            '/',
                            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote'],
                            ['Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', 'Iframe'],
                            ['FontSize'],
                            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
                            ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight']
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });

            element.bind('blur', function () {
                if (CKEDITOR.instances[editor_id] !== undefined) {
                    CKEDITOR.instances[editor_id].destroy();
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Anything that requires a single click works fine (like bold, italics, etc), but trying to change Font Size won't open the drop down.  Or more precisely, the dropdown flashes a bit, but I can't select anything.

I think there's a problem with blur/focus, but I can't figure how to fix it.

**edit:**
Here's the error I get in the console, when I try to change font size...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedText' of null
```

Comment: It will be hard to explain better, but I expect a `z-index` conflict between `ckeditor` and `draggable` style sheets instructions.